# mocking getattr function input

Tags: python, django, python-unittest

this is my test

```
@tag("third_party","mock")
@patch("layers.api.serializers.import_from_service.get_wms_store_layers")
def test_validate_and_publish_WMS_service_layer_serializer(self, mock_wms):
    mock_wms.return_value = ["some_layer","some_other_layer"]
    bar = foo(id=4)
    self.assertEqual(bar,["some_layer","some_other_layer"])
```

and this is my sample code

```
from geos.helpers import stores
def foo(id):
    ows_profile = OWSProfile.objects.get(id=id)
    valid_layers = getattr(stores, f'get_{ows_profile.type}_store_layers')(username=ows_profile.username,password=ows_profile.password,url=ows_profile.url)                                                                                                                                            
    return valid_layers
```

but I got this error

```
AttributeError: <module 'layers.api.serializers.import_from_service' 
    from '/home/sajjad/app/sajjad/layers/api/serializers/import_from_service.py'> 
    does not have the attribute 'get_wms_store_layers'
```

how to fix this

Thanks

Comment: The error itself is quite clear. It's saying it can't find `get_wms_store_layers` in `layers.api.serializers.import_from_service`. Can you check if `get_wms_store_layers` is in `import_from_service`?

Comment: this function is called dynamically by getattr module

Comment: In that case try to mock it from `geos.helpers.stores`, so: `patch("geos.helpers.stores.get_wms_store_layers")`

Comment: it`s correct thanks a lot !!!

Comment: No worries. Have fun!